# Message: [Vertica][VJDBC](4650) ERROR: Schema "information_schema" does not exist

Tags: flyway, vertica

I am not exactly sure why this schema is been searched for. Any flyway experts who worked with vertica ?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more 
research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).  Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the [information_schema is defined as a standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema) implemented by most RDBMSs like MySQL, it is not implemented by Vertica.

In Vertica, the information_schema equivalent SQL structure is the [v_catalog](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/SystemTables/CATALOG/V_CATALOGSchema.htm?Highlight=v_catalog) SQL schema.

The error returned by the Vertica JDBC driver means you are querying erroneously the information_schema. If you are not doing it yourself, it may be a library you're using inadequately (ex : Hibernate would query the information_schema).